# Is my answer possible? (Newtonian Third Law Pairs and Forces, Multiple Choice Word Problem)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

So I recently took a test and the teacher graded my answer correct, yet my friends saw that the other answer was correct and they protest that it should be the right answer:

**The question goes:**

7. *Jared is trying to decide if he will be able to push is car home after it runs out of gas. Which of the following conclusions is most likely to be true?*

**My answer:**

a. *If the car moves, it is because Jared pushed harder on the car than the car pushed on him.*

**My friends answer:**

d. *The car may move. The motion of the car depends only on the forces acting on the car, not the force of the car pushing back on Jared.*

**Image comparison:** [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCwf6.png)

What we're arguing about is that, is my answer or correct or was the teacher wrong?

Note: It's our teacher's first year teaching Physics.

Answer (score 4):

For Jared to push the car home he must cause some acceleration to start the car moving from rest. This is an application of Newton's 2nd law $\vec{F}_{total}=m\vec{a}$. The forces you need to consider are the force Jared can supply and the frictional force on the car.

For  Jared to initially cause the car to accelerate the force he applies must be greater than the frictional force $\vec{F}_{Jared}>\vec{F}_{Frictional}$. Once he gets the car moving the force he applies need only equal the total resistive force on the car, this will allow the car to move with constant linear velocity.

By Newton's third law the car can not "push harder" on Jared than he does on the car, the forces are equal and opposite. Really the crucial point is that the frictional force on Jared is greater than the frictional force on the car. If this were not true he would just slip as he tried to push the car forward.

So your friends were indeed correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will consult my Physics teacher with this.

Comment: I am curious to know what he/she will say.

Comment: I'll confront him on this after the grading period because this is currently keeping my grade on up. Maybe I will confront him on it soon, I'll see. http://i.imgur.com/PkHjXYS.png

Comment: In case francois isn't clear on this, the frictional force being discussed here is between the ground and the car (and the frictional force the ground exerts on the car is equal and opposite to the frictional force the car exerts on the ground, both before and after the car starts rolling), whereas the force between Jared and the car is called the [normal force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_force) (and as Chris2807 said, the normal force of Jared on the car must always be equal and opposite to the normal force of the car on Jared).

Answer (score -2):

Your answer is correct because when looking at change in motion of an object, you look for the "net force" which is the sum of all forces in a scenario.
Examples of the net force being 0 are:

1. The car is parked and Jared is standing next to it, not pushing on the car. Jared exerts 0N on the car which is exerting 0N on Jared. No motion happens
2. Jared turns into the hulk and holds the car back as it drives forward. In this example we'll have the car exerting 900N on Jared (the hulk) with Jared pushing back with 900N. The net force is 0, so no motion occurs.

It is more likely that we'd be thinking about friction as the opposing force deciding whether or not Jared can push the car.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying, but more specifically: How would the example of net force of 0 be in this scenario with Jared pushing the car?

Comment: If the friction between the car and the ground is stronger than Jared's push then the car will remain stationary.

Comment: -1 because of a non-sequitur: the fact that the net force on the car determines whether the car moves does not support the answer of @francois and in fact supports the answer of his friends, so your statement "your answer is correct" is unjustified and appears as a non-sequitur. In fact if we regard a "push" as a "force" then one of Newton's laws makes answer 1 complicated to the point of impossible. (It's not quite metaphysically impossible; but assuming falsehoods cannot cause things, answer (1) plus Newton's second law asserts "the car doesn't move.")

Comment: The magnitude of force acting on the car must be greater than the magnitude of resistive forces. In this case that resistive force is friction which is dissipative and therefore cannot not resist with more force than is given to accelerate the object. The force required to accelerate the object must be greater than the friction can match.

Does that clear things up? I didn't clarify in my answer because I expected that any ambiguities in my answer could be solved through intuition and logic.

Comment: @ChrisDrost and Misc.nerdiness: Thank's for your responses guys, I will look into them more when I have the time to discuss with my friends and/or my teacher who graded this.

Comment: Answer a. cannot possibly be right. If Jared pushes on the car with 241 N, the car pushes back on Jared with 241 N. The car will move (accelerate from rest) based on the vector sum of all the forces acting on the car. The forces acting on Jared only matter, as @Chris2807 said, in whether Jared begins to slide before his force on the car contributes to a net forward sum. But the force back on Jared from the car itself is always equal to Jared's direct push on the car.

Comment: "The magnitude of force acting on the car must be greater than the magnitude of resistive forces." Greater than the magnitude of resistive forces *on what object*? If you mean the force from Jared on the car must be greater than the resistive forces on the car, then you should agree with the friends' answer saying that "The motion of the car depends only on the forces acting on the car", i.e. the horizontal motion depends only on the sum of the horizontal force from Jared acting on the car and the horizontal resistive force acting on the car.